# Plugin error: Photo2shape QGIS Pisa

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, photo2shape

I am trying to install the plugin Photo2Shape to my QGIS Pisa with no success.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

> No module name exifread.

What I need to do is to add geotagged photos to my map that I am working with.

Is this possible with another tool or plugin?

Comment: Apologies but I don't use this plugin. There are several answers in the link provided in my first comment, have you gone through them? If yes and you're still having problems, you can [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/166793/edit) your question to add details :)

Comment: this module correctly work on qgis 1.8.0
let`s try